# select option margin-right is not working

Tags: css

I want a margin-right between the icon font and the option items. Its possible to do this with spaces but I want to do this with a margin-right on the option element like below:

```
select
{
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

select{
  border: 0;
  appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.select_category,
 {
  position: relative;
}

.select_category{
  border-left: 2px solid red;
  border-top: 2px solid red;
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}


.select_category:before {
  content: "\f0ca";
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 1em;
  z-index: 1;
  color: green;
  padding: 15px 18px;

}

.select_category option{
  margin-right:10px;
}
```

But it is not working. Do you know why?

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/8bnu45u2/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should to use a `padding-left` on `.select`. The `.select_category:before` element (which contains the menu icon) has absolute position, therefore a margin for it won't affect the position of any other elements.

https://jsfiddle.net/83Lj0kw6/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can make the parent `flex` to put everything in a row and then your margins will work. Remove the `absolute` positioning on the pseudo elements, and set the `select` to `flex-grow: 1` so it consumes the available space. Remove the vertical padding on the pseudo elements if that makes the container too tall.

```css
select {
  padding: 10px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

select {
  border: 0;
  appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.select_category {
  position: relative;
}

.select_category {
  border-left: 2px solid red;
  border-top: 2px solid red;
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.select_category:before {
  content: "\f0ca";
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  font-size: 1em;
  z-index: 1;
  color: green;
  padding: 15px 18px;
}

.select_category:after {
  content: "\F0D7";
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  color: #d2d6df !important;
  font-size: 2em;
  z-index: 1;
  color: #00af87;
  padding: 15px 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="select_category">
  <select>
    <option selected>Items</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
  </select>
</div>
```